# Query SQL runs slow with group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a sql below, it runs about 30 mins, which is too long for me.

```
SELECT LPP.learning_project_pupilID, SL.serviceID, MAX(LPPO.start_date), SUM(LPPOT.license_mode_value) totalAssignedLicenses
      FROM t_services_licenses SL 
      INNER JOIN t_pupils_offers_services POS ON POS.service_licenseID = SL.service_licenseID 
      INNER JOIN j_learning_projects_pupils_offers LPPO ON LPPO.learning_project_pupil_offerID = POS.learning_project_pupil_offerID
      INNER JOIN j_learning_projects_pupils LPP ON LPPO.learning_project_pupilID = LPP.learning_project_pupilID
      INNER JOIN j_learning_projects_pupils_offers_tracking LPPOT ON LPPOT.pupil_offer_serviceID = POS.pupil_offer_serviceID
      INNER JOIN t_filters_items FI ON FI.itemID = LPP.learning_project_pupilID_for_filter_join  
      WHERE FI.filterID = '4dce2235-aafd-4ba2-b248-c137ad6ce8ca' 
      AND SL.serviceID IN ('OnlineConversationClasses', 'TwentyFourSeven')
      GROUP BY LPP.learning_project_pupilID, SL.serviceID
```

The explain result below(tell me if you can't view the image):

http://images0.cnblogs.com/blog2015/47012/201508/140920298959608.png

I have viewed the profile result, "copying temp data " wasted almost all the time. I know the reason is caused by "group by" functionality, So I did some changes below to verify it:
I removed the MAX, SUM functions as well as the Group By sql and ran it, the time is only cost about 40 seconds, which is ok for us.
So here , I want to know, if there are some other methods to make above sql execute much more faster?

more info, you can find here: http://www.cnblogs.com/scy251147/p/4728995.html

**EDIT:**
From the explain view, I can see that in t_filters_items table, there are about 50802 rows filtered, And this table is not luckily Using temporary to store temp data, which is not a good choice for me . I really don't like "Group By" in MySQL very much.

Comment: The explain shows at least two JOINS that are using indexes. Add your explain here, please

Comment: @BK435, Explain attached.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Explain attached.

Comment: Help................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `CHARACTER SET utf8` on `UUID` columns.  Change to ascii.  Further discussion of uuids and how to further shrink them:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Are there really 50K rows with `FI.filterID = '4dce2235-aafd-4ba2-b248-c137ad6ce8ca'`?

The `GROUP BY` spans two table (`LPP` and `SL`) making it impossible to optimize.  Can that be changed?

The `SUM(...)` is likely to have a bigger value than you expect.  This is because of the `JOINs`.  Try to rewrite the computation of the `SUM` in a subquery.

Are you using InnoDB?  Is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set to about 70% of *available* RAM?

Approximately how many rows in each table?

Comment: Using FI.filterID = '4dce2235-aafd-4ba2-b248-c137ad6ce8ca' to filter the table only, there are 29020 rows total.

Comment: So, the query needs to (1) look at 29020 rows of `FI`, (2) `JOIN` to several other tables, possibly decreasing _or_ increasing the 29020 based on other filtering or join-explosion, and finally (3) do the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: 1.Using FI.filterID = '4dce2235-aafd-4ba2-b248-c137ad6ce8ca' to filter the table only, there are 29020 rows total.
2.No, Base on the Business logic, Group by can't be changed. Until now, I havn't got any good idea to change it.
3.Yes, We use InnoDB. but the size is only 46mb !!
4.table rows count below: t_pupils_offers_services(647778),j_learning_projects_pupils_offers(138702),j_learning_projects_pupils(138182),j_learning_projects_pupils_offers_tracking(736624),t_filters_items(3150753)

Comment: If `serviceID` and `filterID` could be in the _same_ table, then the `WHERE` clause would probably start with a lot fewer rows than 29K.

Comment: And the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  I am harping on that because it feels like it is not big enough to cache all the data -- ( 29K * 6-way JOIN / 100 disk hits/second ) is about 30 minutes.

Comment: Good News, I set the innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2.5GB, and the query takes about 209 seconds to complete the query.  but seems copying to temp table still takes almost all the time.

Comment: "Copying to tmp table" is bogus info.  Yes, a tmp table is needed for this `GROUP BY`.  30min vs 209sec -- that is a typical ratio for non-cached vs cached.  It won't get better without rethinking the query and/or the schema.  Shrinking the UUIDs will help a little.